# An idiomatic phrasing for "though you wouldn't think it"

Tags: traduction, anglais

> … though you wouldn't think it from the way they acted.

Is there a French analogue of “though you wouldn't think it”?

Comment: Could you give a bit more context for the original phrase? It would help to pinpoint the best French equivalent. [The English formulation is being discussed on English Language & Usage.](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/83139/meanings-of-though-you-wouldnt-think-it)

Comment: @Gilles: The sentence in question is: "They're hardworking students, but you wouldn't think it sometimes by the way they always talk in class."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are some idiomatic phrases, but more likely to be heard than to be read.

> alors qu'on n'y aurait pas pensé en les voyant (agir de cette façon)
>
> alors que personne n'y aurait pensé en les voyant...

*"en les voyant": looking at them*

> alors qu'il ne (me, nous, te, etc. or nothing) serait pas venu à l'idée de penser ça en les voyant...
>
> alors que ça ne (me, nous, te, etc. or nothing) serait pas venu à l'idée en les voyant...

There is an old French saying which is often used in similar situations (but you can't 'embed' it in a phrase):

> Qui l'eût cru ?

*Who would have believed this (before seeing the evidence)?*

For instance:

> Le petit chaperon rouge a tué le loup à mains nues et avec ses dents,
>   *alors qu'on n'y aurait pas pensé en la voyant* se promener tranquillement
>   dans la forêt.

Comment: "Qui l'eût cru?" is perfect for my situation, in fact. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Légèrement informel, mais je trouve cela bien plus idiomatique que les autres formulations proposées :

> On ne dirait pas à les voir jouer.
>   On ne dirait pas, vu leur façon de jouer.

On peut utiliser le conditionnel passé (« on ne l'aurait pas dit ») pour marquer que l'apparence est fausse. Le conditionnel présent (« on ne dirait pas ») peut être utilisé que l'apparence soit vraie ou fausse.

« On ne dirait pas » est à peu près équivalent de « *you wouldn't think it* ». Exemple :

> Ce sont des professionnels. On ne dirait pourtant pas à les voir jouer.
>   They are professionals, though you wouldn't think that from the way they act.

Comment: “On ne dirait (pourtant) pas” would often suggest that the speaker doesn't believe the hypothesis is true (or that she tries to moderate its actual value). I perceive “though you wouldn't think it” as less involved, with maybe a slight tendency to strengthen the hypothesis instead. In your example you replaced “it” with “that” and I think that the issue I'm puzzled about lies there. Don't you think “bien qu'on ne l'aurait pas dit” would be a better fit for the original phrase?

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez I perceive both “you wouldn't think it” and “on ne dirait pas” as agnostic regarding to the veracity of the appearance. I think the difference between *it* and *that* is difficult to tell without context (and with context, might be a matter for [english.se]).

Answer (score 2):

The following should fit when the phrase strengthens the hypothesis **it** is reffering to. (Have a look at [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/83139/11859) on EL&U, luckily it is the case in the context you provided.)

> … bien que la façon dont ils se sont comportés ne le laissait pas supposer.

Here “*though you wouldn't think it from [X]*” is translated as “*bien que [X] ne le laissait pas supposer*”.
Instead of *bien que*, which is closer to *even though*, a few alternatives exist:

- *même si*, (also strenghtens the hypothesis)
- *cependant*, *encore que*, *pourtant*, (may weaken the hypothesis)
- *mais*, *quoique* (quite neutral).

---

Within the context you provided, a conditional mood might fit better:

> Ils travaillent dur, bien que la façon dont ils se comportent en classe ne l'aurait pas laissé supposer.

Also, I don't think that “*Qui l'eût cru ?*”, which is nevertheless a very good idea [by Yves](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/3162/79), can be used in this context. It suggests strong surprise, related to a revelation backed by evidence.

And, in casual speak, one would probably use the idiomatic phrasing given [by Gilles](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/3183/79):

> Ils travaillent dur. On (ne) (l') aurait (pourtant) pas dit à la façon dont ils se comportent en classe !

But, be aware that without a conjunction like *bien que*, one could perceive the first sentence as sarcasm.

Answer (score 1):

> ... vous n'auriez pas pensé à la façon dont il l'ont fait (plutôt mot
>   à mot)
>
> ... Vous n'auriez pas imaginé comment ils l'ont réalisé
>
> ... vous ne pouviez pas imaginer comment cela a été fait

N.B. base anglophone trop faible : pas très sûr du temps du verbe avoir : on doit pouvoir aussi utiliser *vous n'auriez pu*

Comment: +1 La tournure avec le verbe imaginer me semble rendre mieux qu'avec le verbe penser.

Answer (score 1):

The translation would be better if we had the whole sentence, but the quoted part would probably translate to :

> ...bien que vous ne l'eussiez pas pensé, eu égard à leurs actes.

or, more casually :

> ...même si vous ne l'auriez pas pensé d'après leurs actes.

or, less litterally :

> ...bien que leurs actes ne le laissaient pas penser.

This third version being, in my humble opinion, more euphonious (euphonic ?) and naturally-sounding in french than the first two.